# Spring data join with specifications - join data from referenced column

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a table which stores the orders. The orders table has an 'One to Many' mapping to another table, which stores ordered item, orderItems. For each row of the orderItems, it refers to a row in the Product table. And I have another table which stores product image, the product image table has a foreign key which points to the product. How can I use JPA specifications to join the product image in the query result of the orders?

Something like:

Order -> [orderId, ... orderItems[],...]

OrderItem -> [orderitemId, ... product,...]

Product -> [productId, productname... ]

ProductImage -> [producdImageId, .... productId...]

I am searching on Order table.

thanks!

Comment: Show as the code you have so far, and in what way it fails to do what you want.

Comment: I don't know how to write the specification for it, e.g searching on the order table, and also fetches the product images